# IntelliJ can't build Gradle project due to missing libraries

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

A while back I started a project that uses libgdx. It supports all platforms so I have a module for each in my project structure. The project worked for a long time and then I updated a few things in the IDE (I don't know what, I just accepted the updates) and nothing would build or run. Since I hadn't really made any changes I backed up my project folder, deleted it, checked out the project from github and tried to start over. Unfortunately no.

Every time I build the project I get this error:

```
Error:Android Gradle Build Target: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/utils/ILogger
```

When I go to file > project structure > Modules > android > dependencies the following libraries are all missing classes:

```
appcompat-v7-25.3.1
support-compat-25.3.1
support-v4-25.3.1
support-core-ui-25.3.1
support-core-utils-25.3.1
support-fragment-25.3.1
support-media-compat-25.3.1
support-vector-drawable-25.3.1
animated-vector-drawable-25.3.1
```

According to the IDE they are all supposed to be located in:

```
PROJECTDIR\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\LIBNAME
```

but \exploded-aar\ doesn't exist.

I have spent the whole day searching and trying different solutions to no avail so I don't even know if this is the problem. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-174239.

Comment: Jeez. So much searching and I never found that because I was searching the exact error string... Thanks man. Made debugging much easier. If you want to post that as an answer ill mark it as correct.

Comment: @CrazyCoder That bug doesn't mention **exploded-aar**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [open bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-174239) logged for this problem. Please follow for updates.

Comment: Thanks, this led to me being able to debug the problem that had nothing to do with what I thought it did.